# Styling Fancybox 2 AJAX

Tags: css, ajax, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox

I have 2 files : index.htm and inner.htm

I'd like to load specific div from inner.htm inside index.htm using Fancybox 2. So I decided to use AJAX but the problem is the AJAX inherited parent CSS. I want inner.htm uses its own CSS.

It works perfectly when I use iFrame but with iFrame I can't load specific DIV.

Please see my points below:

with AJAX
- I can load specific div from inner.htm
- But it uses parent css not its own css

with iFrame
- I can't load specific div except the whole inner.htm page
- But it uses its own css and not parent css as I expected

Any help would be appreciated! THANKS!

> To be clear here, I'm using bootstrap and what I meant to "inner.htm
>   should uses its own css" is it    should load its own bootstrap.css so
>   that it would be shrinked to the modal box. What I have now is it's
>   inherited parent's bootstrap.css and not shrinked to the modal box
>   (horizontal scrollbar appears).
>
> So I want inner.htm in modal box to load its col-md-4 not parent's
>   col-md-4. Hope it's clear now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Where is the code hidden?

Comment: @rpax Not sure about your question but I don't have the demo code.

Answer (score 0):

add its css to parent css so it will load that one

see your code and add the class which is used by fancybox popup like

ie

```
.fancybox-iframe .your-div{}
```

i hope this will work

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, I'm using bootstrap so when the inner.htm is loaded in the modal box it uses parent css so the horizontal scrollbar appears. When I use iFrame, it loads its own bootstrap css and automatically shrink to the modal box.